# Can you force users to put all new content in at least one Organic Group?

Tags: organic-groups, forms

In Drupal 6, I would like to make sure users always add their Group content nodes to at least one Organic Group. I have a module that enforces a maximum number of groups, but I don't think it does a minimum.

The site is entirely groups-based and I don't really want people posting outside of a group.

I could certainly write a module for this if one does not exist, or it might be as simple as a form_alter() function.

Comment: How about opening up your question to D7 (and also D8?), now that D6 is no longer supported? If you do, let me know (via an extra comment to ping me). I'd add a straight forward solution to do so, using OG's alternative for D7 and D8 ... PS: great podcasts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In admin/og/og search the "Audience required" setting, and change it from *optional* to *required*, if you don't need it for administer accounts also.